# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: hibernate

Here is my code:

```
airelines = em.createQuery(
                    "select distinct rt.aireline from Route as rt join rt.aireline as a1"
                    + " join rt.destination as dst "
                    + " where a1.country = :country and dst.city = :city ", Airline.class)
                   .setParameter("country", "France")
                     .setParameter("city", "Miami")
                    .getResultList(); 

                            showAirlines(airelines);
```

I have these errors. Please, how can resolve these errors. Kind regards.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    
   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: aireline of: flights.Route [select distinct rt.aireline from flights.Route as rt join rt.aireline as a1 join rt.destination as dst  where a1.country = :country and dst.city = :city ]
at
```

Here is my Route class:

```
@Entity
public class Route implements Serializable {
private String airlineCode;
@ManyToOne
@Id
private Airline airline;
private String sourceCode;
@ManyToOne
@Id
private Airport source;
private String destinationCode;
@ManyToOne
@Id
private Airport destination;
private Boolean codeshare;
private Short stops;
private String equipment;
 //Getters and Setters
}
```

Many Thanks. Please, how can resolve these errors. Kind regards.

Comment: Can you show us the Route class

Comment: @pL4Gu33 https://www.dropbox.com/s/35espch5zv54xn8/Route.java?dl=0

Comment: please add the class here (edit your question and insert the code there)

Comment: @pL4Gu33 my error is: aireline  should be airline (without "e")

Comment: kindly share your Route class here

Comment: @codeLover  Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is just a spelling mistake. You have attribute named **airline** in your Entity while you are using **rt.aireline** in your query. Just replace **rt.aireline** to **rt.airline** in your query. It should work...